# scrolling behavior not function correctly when using mui Theme with MuiDrawer and a menu

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, tailwind-css, vite, typescript-typings

muiTheme is changingig behaviour of portal components.

```
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiPopover: {
      defaultProps: {
        container: rootElement
      }
    },
    MuiPopper: {
      defaultProps: {
        container: rootElement
      }
    },
    MuiDialog: {
        defaultProps: {
          container: rootElement,
        },
     },
  }
});
```

after using the default behaviour of Menu (the page don't scroll when menu is open) is not working properly , I've tried disableScrollLock but its not working properly.
i am using this theme because its let me apply tailwind css to the mui components.
I am using vite+React+Typescript for the project and mui and tailwind for styling.

I have tried the disableScrollLock but its not working as expectecd.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.